# Toggle CSS class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to get this to work. What I want to do is have jQuery add / remove (or toggle) a class which has `display:none` on it

jQuery

```
  <script type ="text/javascript">

    //Event Triggers
    $("#cbVitamins").click(function(evt){
      $("#products h2.product-type[data-type=vitamin]").parent().addClass("hideItem");
    });
  </script>
```

CSS

```
  <style>
    .hideItem {
      display:none;
    }
  </style>
```

HTML Button to hook event onto

```
      <div>
        <span>Show: </span>
        <input id="cbVitamins" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="cbVitamins">Vitamins</label>
      </div>
```

HTML → add `.hideItem` class to the `li` element

```
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-C6614">
    <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-c.jpg" alt="Vitamin C - Product Photo">
    <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Vitamin C</h2>
</li>
```

what its supposed to do:

[image]

Comment: use `.toggleClass()`

Comment: Or, if `display:none` is all it does, even `toggle()`

Comment: Your `h2.product-type` selector doesn't match the class on the h2 element. It should be `h2.product-name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're targeting the class `product-type` with your jQuery, when you're actually using the class `product-name` in your HTML.

You can toggle visibility with the [**`.toggle()` method**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) -- you don't need to create a separate class:

```js
//Event Triggers
$("#cbVitamins").click(function(evt) {
  $("h2.product-name[data-type=vitamin]").parent().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span>Show: </span>
  <input id="cbVitamins" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <label for="cbVitamins">Vitamins</label>
</div>

<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-C6614">
  <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-c.jpg" alt="Vitamin C - Product Photo">
  <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Vitamin C</h2>
</li>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks so much :) . Didn't realize I had typed in `type` instead of `name` that works as well. By the way, doesn't parents() target all parent classes up until `html` element? But in this instance, parents() is only target the next level up for me, which is what I want though. I thought only `parentsUntil()` does this? or am i thinking of `parent()` vs `parents()`?

Comment: Are you sure that `parents()` is **only** targeting the next level up for you? In both your example and my answer, we're using the singular `parent()`. I've just double-checked, and using `parents()` in my answer code does indeed toggle **all** visible elements. Don't forget that `parentsUntil()` is **exclusive**, and you can always **chain** `parent()` if need be; `element.parent().parent()` is perfectly valid.

Comment: never thought of parent().parent(). There's lots of other parent classes enclosing the data I had (but omitted), but I read the jQuery documentation so now I understand the distinction between `parent()` and `parents()`. thanks for info

Answer (score 2):

> you use of `$("#products`... in jquery.i can't see element with this `id` in html code.

*Change code like this:*

```
$('#cbVitamins').click(function(){
    $('.product-item').toggleClass('hideItem');
})
```

*Note:I prefer use of `change` event.*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cbVitamins').click(function(){
    $('.product-item').toggleClass('hideItem');
  })
})
```

```css
.hideItem {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div>
  <span>Show: </span>
  <input id="cbVitamins" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="cbVitamins">Vitamins</label>
</div>
<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-C6614">
  <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-c.jpg" alt="Vitamin C - Product Photo">
  <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Vitamin C</h2>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks this was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery hide() and show() methods.

```
$('.clickButton').click(function() {
    $('.element').hide();
});

$('.clickButton').click(function() {
    $('.element').show();
});
```

Hope thats help.

Comment: You *can*, but why would that work if `.addClass("hideItem")` didn't work?

Comment: Does `toggle()` without any parameter inside of that essentially do both `hide()` and `show()` or is different?

Comment: Yes it does indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle class using jquery

```js
$("#cbVitamins").on('change', function() {
  $(".product-name").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Show: </span>
  <input id="cbVitamins" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <label for="cbVitamins">Vitamins</label>
</div>

<li class="product-item" data-prod_id="V-C6614">
  <img class="product-image" src="images/products/vitamin-c.jpg" alt="Vitamin C - Product Photo">
  <h2 class="product-name" data-type="vitamin">Vitamin C</h2>
</li>
```

Comment: does `change` event just encompass more things than just `click` when describing event handler?